# can java timer works faster?

Tags: java, timer

i am currently using the java timer to schedule my program to print screen

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new PrintScreen(),0,1);
```

this is my code, it schedule to do PrintScreen with 0s delay and 0.001s/image

can it work more faster due to the result image still have some lagging during the printscreen.

i am currently using the java printscreen at every 0.001 s. i have attached the image as 1.jpeg and 2.jpeg

but i hope the image output will somehow similiar to image3.jpg, image4.jpg and image5.jpg
which can see the tiny movement

1.jpg : http://www.java.net/sites/default/files/1.jpeg

2.jpg : http://www.java.net/sites/default/files/2.jpeg

image3.jpg : http://www.java.net/sites/default/files/image3.jpg

image4.jpg : http://www.java.net/sites/default/files/image4.jpg

image5.jpg : http://www.java.net/sites/default/files/image5.jpg

any suggestion for this ? thanks in advance for the reply .

==================================================================================update
this is my whole code for print screen

```
        Toolkit tool = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension d = tool.getScreenSize();
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(d);
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        ss.setScreenCount();
        int index = ss.getScreenCount();
        String screenFileName = "screenshot_" + index + ".jpeg";  
        File f = new File(screenFileName);
        BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture(rect);
        ImageIO.write(img,"jpeg",f);

        int totalClient = ss.getTotalClient();
        for(int i=0;i<totalClient;i++)
        {
            RshScp rsThread = new RshScp(screenFileName,i,ss);
            Thread rs = new Thread(rsThread,"RshScpThread");        
            rs.start();
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking 1000 screenshots in a second seems difficult to do, and rather strange considering most displays update at nowhere near that rate. It looks like you're trying to capture video. Video tends to run between 24 and 60 frames per second. 1000 frames per second is a little absurd.

Comment: Also, if at that rate (1000fps) you can't seem to capture the desired detail it means your computer simply can't handle it, event at lower rates, and you should consider other options. Maybe explain us what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: thanks for the reply . erm .. if i want to run 30 frrames /seconds , which is 30 images in 1 seconds, how to implement that ?

Comment: i am using a machine (machine A) to display video , and then in machine A , it print screen and send to another machine (machine B) which only display whatever machine A send to its .

Comment: To do 30fps, you'd set the rate to 1/30. Kind of simple really.

Comment: in timer there is using 1000 to represent 1seconds , if i want to set it 1/30 then is how ?? sorry for my ignorance .. is it 0.0333 * 1000 ? but i remember that it must be an integer right ?

Comment: I think the easiest way to go would be 1000/30. This is just basic mathematics here.

Comment: i put the code to become --> timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new PrintScreen(),0,1000/30);

but i still cannot get the result which i want like image 3,4 and 5 which attached above .

Comment: Probably your image-saving code is just too slow.
What is your larger goal?

Comment: i have update my code on above , please have a look . my larger goal is to let the file to capture 30 frames/seconds and then send the image to another machine . but when i run the program, there is some lagging in between 2 images (1.jpg and 2.jpg) .. i wish the image after capture screen will be like (image 3,4 and 5.jpg) .. the image are already attached on above . thanks again for the reply

Comment: i have make a measurement on how long time it needs to capture 30frames. it should be is 30 frames/second but when i run the timer measurement for 5 times and the mean time to capture 30 frames is 3.6 seconds .. is there any way can fasten the capture screen things ?

Comment: @Eric, yes. Use appropriate video streaming software. [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/), for instance, enables you to [stream your desktop and visualize the stream in another computer](http://betterlogic.com/roger/2010/07/how-to-use-vlc-as-a-free-open-source-alternative-to-playon-tv/).

Comment: ok .. thanks @TelmoMarques for the reply and suggestion, i will go and try it out .. thanks a lot ..